# Tortoise SVN Client is not working in windows server 2003 R2

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Apache as server for SVN. I have installed TortoiseSVN client on the Windows Server machine. The options of SVN are not showing up when I right click on a particular folder. But the installation shows successfull. And the same is working on Windows XP machines. 
Can anyone tell what the problem would be.

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill `explorer.exe` in Task Manager and start it again:

1. Press **Ctrl-Alt-Delete**,
2. Start **Task Manager**,
3. Go to **Processes**,
4. Select `explorer.exe,`
5. Choose to **End Process**,
6. Go to **Applications**,
7. Select **New Task...**,
8. Enter `explorer`,
9. Press **OK**,
10. Close **Task Manager** window.

If it does not help, restart your machine.